# Which hard disk is causing these ATA errors?

Tags: hard-drive, hardware, sata

in my `journalctl -xb` I see this:

```
ata1.00: exception Emask 0x50 SAct 0x6000 SErr 0x4890800 action 0xe frozen
ata1.00: irq_stat 0x0c400040, interface fatal error, connection status changed
ata1: SError: { HostInt PHYRdyChg 10B8B LinkSeq DevExch }
ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
ata1.00: cmd 60/00:68:a8:fc:5e/01:00:00:00:00/40 tag 13 ncq dma 131072 in
         res 40/00:70:a8:fd:5e/00:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x50 (ATA bus error)
ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
ata1.00: cmd 60/00:70:a8:fd:5e/01:00:00:00:00/40 tag 14 ncq dma 131072 in
         res 40/00:70:a8:fd:5e/00:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x50 (ATA bus error)
ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
ata1: hard resetting link
```

and I suspect hard disk problems

But I have more than 1 hard disk. How do I find out which one is the problem?

Comment: Does this help: https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/disk-check.html.en

Comment: That says all disks are ok. Even if that reported problems, I would like a way to directly link these logs messages with a disk.

Comment: Is this working?  `cat /sys/bus/scsi/devices/1\:0\:0\:0/model`

Comment: I don't know what that means. I don't know how to tell whether it's working if I don't know what it's supposed to do.

Comment: This command should show which model of hard-drive is connected on the 1. scsi bus. Another way is to open the computer and look to the Mainboard slots they have normally numbers.

Comment: Am I looking for 1 because of the 1 in "ata1"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Earlier in the same `journalctl -xb`, I found this:

`ata1.00: ATA-10: WDC WD2003FZEX-00SRLA0, 01.01A01, max UDMA/133`

That is a model telling me which drive it is.

The comment that suggested `cat /sys/bus/scsi/devices/1\:0\:0\:0/model` is not correct.
The scsi device 1:0:0:0 is not necessarily the same device as ata1.00